# How to use find to match substring of files to be concatted?

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg, find

complete beginner here, so sorry if this is painfully obvious. I'm trying to write a shell script to [ffmpeg concat protocol](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#protocol) a bunch of split video files together by looping over the files and dynamically adding the correct parts to be joined together. For example, turning this:

titlea-00001234-01.ts
titlea-00001234-02.ts
titlea-00001234-03.ts
titleb-00001234-01.ts
titleb-00004321-02.ts
titleb-00004321-03.ts

into this:

titlea-00001234.mp4
titleb-00004321.mp4

by doing this

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:titlea-00001234-01.ts|titlea-00001234-02.ts|titlea-00001234-03.ts" -c copy titlea-00001234.mp4
ffmpeg -i "concat:titleb-00001234-01.ts|titleb-00001234-03.ts|titleb-00001234-03.ts" -c copy titleb-00001234.mp4
```

But what I'm having trouble with is using find to add the correct parts after `"concat:"`.

Here's my best attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in /path/to/files/*.ts
    do
        if [[ "$i" =~ (-01) ]]
        then
            j="${i##*/}"
            k="${j%-0*}"
            ffmpeg -i `concat:( find /path/to/files/ -type f -name "{$k}*" -exec printf "%s\0" {} + )` -c copy /path/to/output/"{$k%.ts}.mp4"
        else
            echo "no files to process"
            exit 0
        fi
    done
```

But this gives an error of "No such file or directory".

***Edit This solution worked perfectly for my needs https://stackoverflow.com/a/75807616/21403800 Thanks @pjh and everyone else for taking the time to help***

Comment: please update the question with the **complete** error message; I'm *assuming* it's complaining that `concat:(` does not exist ... ???

Comment: Can you check your specifications? Perhaps `titleb-00001234-01.ts` should be `titleb-00004321-01.ts`, but in your command `ffmpeg -i "concat:titleb-00001234-01.ts|titleb-00001234-03.ts|titleb-00001234-03.ts" -c copy titleb-00001234.mp4` I only see `1234` and not `4321`.

Comment: you're searching in directory `/path/to/files/` for files of interest, but you're not including this directory in the actual `ffmpeg` command; are you sitting in `/path/to/files/` when you run your script?

Comment: Before writing the complete script, test what is possible with `find`. Do you want something like `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "titlea*ts" -printf "%f|" | sed -r 's/(.*)|/fmpeg -i "concat:\1" -c copy titlea-00001234.mp4/'` ?

Comment: At the very least, tell us which line in your script produces the error, and state the **complete** error message.

Comment: @WalterA Sorry I did mean to type titleb-00004321 my bad.

Comment: @markp-fuso Your assumption was right sorry about not posting the full error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

shopt -s nullglob

cd path_to_files || exit 1

prev_base=
for tsfile in *-[[:digit:]][[:digit:]].ts ''; do
    base=${tsfile%-*}
    if [[ $base == "$prev_base" ]]; then
        iarg+="|$tsfile"
    else
        [[ -n $prev_base ]] && echo ffmpeg -i "$iarg" -c copy "${prev_base}.mp4"
        iarg="concat:$tsfile"
        prev_base=$base
    fi
done
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` makes globs expand to nothing when nothing matches (otherwise they expand to the glob pattern itself, which is almost never useful in programs).
- The `''` before the semicolon in `for tsfile in *-[[:digit:]][[:digit:]].ts ''; do` is an empty string sentinel to cause the  last batch of files matched by the `*-[[:digit:]][[:digit:]].ts` pattern to be processed by the code in the loop body.
- See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${tsfile%-*}`.
- The code currently just prints the `ffmpeg` commands to be executed.  Remove the `echo` to have it actually run the `ffmpeg` commands.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility might be

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *-[0-9][0-9].ts; do
    prefix=${file%??????}
    tgtfile=$prefix.mp4
    [[ -e $tgtfile ]] && continue
    printf -v filelst '%s|' "$prefix"-[0-9][0-9].ts
    ffmpeg -i "concat:${filelst%?}" -c copy "$tgtfile"
done
```